# Scraping angellist start-up data

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I want to **scrape** data in a spreadsheet from this site [Angel.co startup list](https://angel.co/social-network-2) i have tried many ways,but it shows an error. used IMPORTXML,IMPORTHTML in spreadsheet it's not working

format : startup name, location, category

Thanks in advance for help.

tried to used this below request method to **scrape** data however it shows no output.

```
import requests

URL = 'https://angel.co/social-network-2'


headers = {
   "Host": "www.angel.co",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux armv8l; rv:88.0) 
   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0",
   "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
   "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
   "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
   "Referer": "https://angel.co/social-network-2",
   "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
   "via": "1.1 google"
}

datas = requests.get(URL, headers=headers).json()
import re

for i in datas['data']:
    for j in re.findall('class="uni-link">(.*)</a>',i['title']):
    print(j)
```

Comment: What exactly have tried? Where is you code?

Comment: javascript content cant be scrapped into google sheets

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraped__, __scraping__) not scrap. ‘To scrap’ means to throw away like rubbish :-(

Comment: @vish Your question is getting confused. please edit the question properly. You can scrape this website with python selenium easily.

Comment: @arun n a can you please tell me how selenium helps scrape this data entierly ?

Comment: @vish Please watch this https://www.linkedin.com/posts/arun-saanthi_python3-selenium-automations-activity-6656001728028176384-YumL. This was done with selenium, you can check the code here https://github.com/arun-n-a/linkedin-ppl-search-scraper . You can  refer to this for learning.

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid that you will not be able to scrape this webpage.

The problem is that they use cloudflare protection that is specially designed to prevent such automatic bot scraping...

Only suggestion would be to accept this fact and not waste your time...

Comment: i have tried cloudscraper and it worked for me once and if i do it again it shows 403 error